# {{> yield}} causes a blank page when Router.route(uri, {name: templateName })

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes

I'm new to MeteorJS. I was reading up [Discover Meteor](https://book.discovermeteor.com) while trying to build an app of my own (instead of the demo app [Microscope](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope)). When setting up a `router.js` I encountered this problem.

`{{> yield}}` in the layout Template is causing a blank page on `/` when I tried using `name` for routing:

```
Router.route('/', {name: 'home' })
```

(where home is a template defined in the client repository.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conclusion:

I checked my iron-router's version in `.meteor/versions` and realized it was  0.9.3, while the one in the [demo app](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope) is 1.0.0.

I tried updating it

```
meteor update iron:router
```

but it can only be updated to 0.9.4 due to other packages I have. 0.9.4 is the latest compatible version.

So this appears to be a backward-compatibility issue. Somehow the function

```
Router.route(uri, {name: templateName });
```

doesn't seem to work with `{{> yield}}`, which is why I'm getting a blank page.

(although using `{{yield}}` would output the string `[object object]`).

### Solution:

I used a different function to route instead

```
Router.route(templateName, {path: uri});
```

together with `map`:

```
Router.map ->
  @route 'home', 
  path: '/'
  return

#this is CoffeeScript
```